# Installing proj4 on Mac

Tags: r

Trying to install ggalt for R and one of the dependencies is failing to install. The Proj4 dependency returns the following error

```
configure: error: libproj and/or proj_api.h not found in standard search locations.

*** Install PROJ.4 and if necessary set PKG_CPPFLAGS/PKG_LIBS accordingly.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘proj4’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/proj4’
```

proj is installed using homebrew as is R

- R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
- proj Rel. 6.1.0, May 15th, 2019

I am guessing that I need to set the PKG_CPPFLAGS/PKG_LIBS, how is this accomplished in R or RStudio?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi. No I am afraid I did not. Ended up uninstalling R with Homebrew and installing manually.